# Accessing WebCam with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Does anyone have any experience with trying to access a webcam through node? I can't seem to find any prior attempts at this.

To expand a bit - I have a nodeJS server running, and I want to be able to access the webcam on the same box Node is running (so really, I'm using node more as a client implementation). Some things I wanted to do - get an image from the webcam, or, it'd be awesome if I could get a stream to the webcam that I pipe to another server and stream to other clients ;)

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: what is your system? if it's linux, try to look at V4L capture example (there are plenty, eg http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/capture-example.html ) and create simple one user tcp server in C and multiplex/distribute data/connections on node side by connecting from node to it. Another option would be using phone camera accessible via wifi

Comment: Preferably the system is Windows. Also, your suggestion is actually quite complex and would take a bit of time to implement, was hoping for something a bit simpler :)

Comment: with networked phone webcam it's actually straightforward and os-agnostic

Comment: https://github.com/wearefractal/camera is a library I wrote for accessing system cameras via OpenCV

Comment: I have implemented a node.js module for webcam frame grabbing (camelot [1]) but it runs on linux through v4l. [1]: http://blog.rassemblr.com/2011/07/camelot-non-blocking-webcam-frame-grabbing-and-real-time-controlling-node-js-module/

Answer (score 17):

I don't think there's anything specific to Node.js when it comes to working with webcams, the concepts are generally the same no matter what language or server you're using. The hardware involved and the interfaces to that hardware is what should define your solution.

The simplest case would be to serve individual snapshots that are periodically saved to disk by the webcam's included software, or you can make [a system call](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) that invokes a [local process](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Webcam-HOWTO/#COMMAND) or [program](http://batchloaf.wordpress.com/commandcam/) to save a snapshot on demand.  You can then serve a page using Node.js that periodically refreshes the latest snapshot.

Alternatively, you can interface directly with the webcam hardware using a controller tailored to the operating system ([DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx), [Windows Image Acquisition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368(VS.85).aspx), [IKPictureTaker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImagePicker_Class/IKImagePicker_Reference.html), [V4L2](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/), etc.) and create a [live video stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) using Node.js as the transport mechanism.

If your webcam has a network interface and already offers a streaming server, you might want to look into a reverse proxy solution instead, using nginx or Apache for example. [Here is a solution](http://www.kutukupret.com/2011/04/15/nginx-vlc-streaming-cheap-webcam/) where nginx is being used to proxy a webcam stream formatted by VLC.

[Here is a creative solution that captures a video stream by taking individual frames, encoding the image data, and using websockets to push the image data to a canvas element on a client page](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/), using Node.js as the intermediate server.

Comment: But you are basically nor suggesting to implement drivers or use ffmpeg or vlc to access the device, encode and decode. I tried with ffmpeg to build a portable solution, but even only for one OS is very complex, and I fear testing in all hardware/OS combinations could take lots of work. opencv based solutions are also hard to install. I research projects claiming to support portable APIs for this but nor they doesn't work or depend on native programs that often are hard to install and must be manually....

Comment: That's why I decided to use puppeteer (chrome headless version) which although it could seem not lightweight it's very portable and needs little test (see my answer for the project). It's working nice, already using on a desktop application (rendering in gtk / cairo and qt). I wonder why nobody came up with this solution before... Now working on a CLI and other features like desktop recording, audio capture, etc. Feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to use node.js library [node-webcam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webcam)

```
Webcam.capture( "test_picture", function( err, data ) {} );
```

But I suppose it is simple wrapper of fswebcam.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use OpenCV with Node to access your camera... this article will give you a basic overview.
https://community.risingstack.com/opencv-tutorial-computer-vision-with-node-js/

Another way is to search by *camera* on npm repository, you will find a lot of modules that deal with webcams.

Comment: That's are native bindings for node.js but unfortunately it doesn't support camera  :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on my own library based on puppeteer (chrome headless browser) and so is 100% portable and works acceptably fine (40fps in my machine for video size 480x320) : https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-capture. Has different ways of consuming the video stream and a command line API too. Very new project so feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score -5):

accessing web in node application is very simple we just need to use html5 getUserMedia() method to do that and reaming part is very easy here is complete code please node i am using express framework:

**Step 1.** My layout.jade file in which i am accessing web cam

```
extends layout
block content
  div(class="container" id="Cool" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="formController")
    h2.blue.red#header("property"="pValue") Capture your image from webcam
    div.row
     div.col-md-6
       video#video(autoplay='')
     div.col-md-6
       canvas#canvas(width='640', height='480')
    div
      button#snap Capture
      button#new New
      button(id="upload" ng-click="uploadImage()") Upload


  script(type="text/javascript").
   // Put event listeners into place
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      video = document.getElementById("video"),
      videoObj = { "video": true },
      errBack = function(error) {
      console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
      };
      // Put video listeners into place
      if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
      navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
      video.src = stream;
      video.play();
      }, errBack);
      } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
      }, errBack);
      } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
      }, errBack);
      }
      // Trigger photo take
      document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      // Littel effects
      //$('#video').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#canvas').fadeIn('slow');
      //$('#snap').hide();
      //$('#new').show();
      // Allso show upload button
      //$('#upload').show();
      });
      // Capture New Photo
      document.getElementById("new").addEventListener("click", function() {
      //$('#video').fadeIn('slow');
      //$('#canvas').fadeOut('slow');
      //$('#snap').show();
      //$('#new').hide();
      });
      // Upload image to sever
      document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("click", function(){
      var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
       console.log(dataUrl);

      });
      }, false);   
   var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
   mainApp.controller("formController", function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.uploadImage = function () {
         var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url:  "/captureImage",
            data: {
               base64: document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL()
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
          });
        request.success(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
        request.error(function(serverResponse, status, headers, config) {
           alert("failure");
        });
      };
   });
```

**Step 2.** my routes file in which i hand or save my uploaded image

```
router.get('/captureImage', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('captureImage', { title: 'Capture Image and upload' });
});

router.post('/captureImage', function(req, res, next) {
    //console.log("FormData "+ req.body.base64);
    var base64Data = req.body.base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    fs.writeFile("uploads/out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            }else{
            res.send(JSON.stringify({'status': 1, 'msg': 'Image Uploaded'}));
        }
    });
});
```

For complete tutorial please follow link [Accessing WebCam with NodeJS and save click image - TrinityTuts](https://trinitytuts.com/accessing-webcam-with-nodejs-and-save-click-image/)

Comment: I don't think that question is about "how to access the web cam from angular js using browser"

Comment: I agree with @ManasviSareen, you answer another question.