# Access Raspberry Pi Camera from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, camera, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to access the raspberry pi camera from Node.js? How would one go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808805/accessing-webcam-with-nodejs .. maybe helpful perhaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [node-raspicam](https://github.com/troyth/node-raspicam/)

" A Node.js-based controller module for the Raspberry Pi camera based on a command structure similar to Johnny-Five. Currently implemented as a wrapper for structuring a command line process call using child_process.exec from within Node. "