# Is there a way to access webcam in windows through node js application without using any external npm library

Tags: node.js, windows, webcam, directshow, windows-rt

Is there a way to access  webcam in windows through node js application without using any external npm library .

I have figured out a way using c++ binding to use windows runtime apis ,is this the only way or i am missing something

Comment: Did you see this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808805/accessing-webcam-with-nodejs You might look at some of the source code in node-webcam and see if there is anything you could reuse if you don't want to use any libraries.